# Sqoop snappy compression not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, snappy

I have the following sqoop script which is supposed to get the data in parquet and use the snappy compression.

```
sqoop import \ 
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--connect '<Connection URL>' \
--query 'select * from <db_name>.<table_name> where $CONDITIONS' \
--username <username> \
--password <password> \
--split-by '<split-by-key>' \
-m=4 \
--input-null-string '' \
--input-null-non-string '' \
--inline-lob-limit 0 \
--target-dir <hdfs/location/where/files/should/land> \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
--as-parquetfile \
--map-column-java NOTES_DETAIL=String,NOTES=String \
```

Once the script is finished successfully, I go into the hdfs location ['hdfs/location/where/files/should/land'] and see that neither snappy compression is applied nor the _SUCCUSS file showing up. Why is this happening?

This is what I see when I list the files in that folder

```
21cbd1a6-d58b-4fdc-b332-7433e582ce0b.parquet
3956b0ff-58fd-4a87-b383-4fecc337a72a.parquet
3b42a1a9-4aa7-4668-bdd8-41624dec5ac6.parquet
```

As you can see no .snappy in file name nor _SUCCESS file.

Answer (score 2):

You won't see at the extension of a Parquet file which compression was used. In Parquet files, the data is internally compressed in chunks. With the codec selection, you specify which codec should be used for each chunk in the whole file. Still, the Parquet specification allows you to change the compression codec in each data chunk, thus you could mix the compression codecs inside of a Parquet file. Some tools produce `.snappy.parquet` files to indicate the chosen compression level but that is only decorative as the compression information is stored in the file's metadata.

To check if your Parquet file has been snappy-compressed, inspect the files using `parquet-tools`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I verified my files are in snappy compression. However, why am I not getting the _SUCCESS file? At the end of each sqoop load I am get a _SUCCESS file, but I am not getting it here.

Comment: @user2159301: In lots of Linux practice _SUCCESS file is used to indicate the state of the job in that batch is successful, the file is usually with the 0 size.

Answer (score 0):

Enable compression using below parameter:

-z,--compress

Reference : https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html